# Override JS message in

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

This is how I tried to override function in a thread, generally, I just changed `display_order: ORDER.ASC`, to `display_order: ORDER.DESC`. Basically, my goal is just to change the order of messages in Discus.
but my code has no effect, but I get a message in the log that it is running

```xml
  <template id="config.assets_backend" name="config assets" inherit_id="web.assets_backend" >
                    <xpath expr="." position="inside" >
                        <script type="text/javascript" src="/config/static/src/js/thread.js" ></script>
                    </xpath>
                </template>
```

```js
 odoo.define('config.thread', function (require) {
        "use strict";

        var Thread  = require('mail.ChatThread');
         var ORDER = {
          ASC: 1,
         DESC: -1,
          };

        console.log("ChatThread: ", Thread);

        Thread.include({
            init: function (parent, options) {
                this._super.apply(this, arguments);
                this.options = _.defaults(options || {}, {
                    display_order: ORDER.DESC,
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

**UPDATE for the bounty:**
As I tried to debug at this line `this._super.apply(this, arguments);` in arguments I receive display_order: 1 so my guess is that this line

```
this.options = _.defaults(options || {}, {
                    display_order: ORDER.DESC,
                });
```

not working properly. so any suggestions.

Comment: Maybe you should read the error message properly? ;-) incl**i**ude

Comment: Ups... my stupid mistake.. but thanx for help...

Comment: Just happens to everyone.

Comment: Unfortunatly even after i fixed my typo, code does nothing...

Comment: Hopefully someone can help you further, i can't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is solution for my problem:

```js
odoo.define('modulename.ChatThread',
    function (require) {
    "use strict";
    var core = require('web.core');
    var MailThread = require('mail.ChatThread');
    var Thread = MailThread.include({
    className: 'o_mail_thread',
    init: function (parent, options) {
        this._super.apply(this, arguments);
        this.options.display_order = -1;
    },
    });
});
```